# How can I hide labels in Google Chart?

Tags: google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm new to **[Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)**, and I'm trying to learn it.

I have

[image]

---

Here is my option

```
      var options = {
          width: 400,
          height: 240,
          colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']

      };
```

---

[`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/xu5z2pt4/)

How do I hide the label : Work, Eat ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.... I found it. I realize that just need to add another option `legend: 'none',`

```
      var options = {
          width: 400,
          height: 240,
          colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6'],
          legend: 'none'
      };
```

[image]

Comment: HI @Cyber8200 , can you tell me how can i remove that percentages from chart..??